# Yammer SDK - Get user information (JSON to PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, json

I've just implemented the Yammer Login SDK on my web application. Once logged in, I can see the user information just fine with this code:

```
yam.getLoginStatus(
function(response) {
if (response.authResponse) {
  console.log("logged in");

  yam.platform.request({
    url: "users/current.json", //this is one of many REST endpoints that are available
    method: "GET",
    data: {    //use the data object literal to specify parameters, as documented in the REST API section of this developer site
      "page": "2",
    },
    success: function (user) { //print message response information to the console
      alert("The request was successful.");
      console.dir(user);

    },
    error: function (user) {
      alert("There was an error with the request.");
    }
  });

}
else {
  alert("not logged in")
}
}
);
```

However this only shows my information as a JSON "Object" in my console log. 
I want to access all this GET information so that I can upload this information into a MySQL database. This is how I see the info in my console log:

[image: JSON Object]

I basically need to access this information so I can use it in PHP.

Comment: `GET` information ? you mean your whole HTTP request response?

Comment: @hassan yes that's what I mean

Comment: print the whole `response` object into your console and select your desired element.